# Angularjs app requires thousands of bindings - a better way?

Tags: angularjs, performance

I have a fairly simple angular app that works great.

However one module is VERY intense and requires thousands of bindings (think something like trello where a trello board could have hundreds of cards, lists, etc., each with many bindings).

What is the right way to develop something like this in angular?

I'm almost thinking I should do this one module in strictly html, css, and javascript.

What's the recommended way to do a heavy, intense module with many bindings (well above the recommended 2,000 limit) in an angular app?

Comment: Try to use one-time bindings where possible

Comment: if... you try to use components, you can create a unidirectional binds... and if you use immutable techniques (https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/) you can have a stable page.